# Alternative to 'ThreadContext' in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, threadcontext

I have been working on a project which uses log4j2, and in this project I use ThreadContext. Now I'm back to working with log4j (1), and it doesn't provide ThreadContext. Are there any good alternatives that I can ThreadContext with? Google searches hasn't given my any good ideas yet, so I hope someone here might have some input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) directly. See [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) for more details. Also see this [example](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/) on how to use it.

Basically you will set your attribute using:

```
MDC.put("userName", "test");
```

And then in the logger you can log that information like:

```
#note the %X{userName} - this is how you fetch data from Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %-4r [%t] %5p %c %x - %m - user: %X{userName}%n
```

Or if using xml config, you can configure a separate appender with a filter for that user, like:

```
<appender name="Test" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="my.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-8p [%-5t] %C{2}:%-12M - %m%n user: %X{userName}" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
                  <param name="StringToMatch" value=" user: test " />
                  <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
          </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
    </appender>
```

And then enable a logger only for that appender:

```
<logger name="com.example.Clazz" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="Test"/>
</logger>
```

This way you can see the logs related only to user `test`.